# iOSpush notification return code 102

Tags: php, ios

I'm running push notification form server to my iphone.

> ... ... // Encode the payload as JSON
>
> $payload = json_encode($body);
>
> // Build the binary notification
>
> $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n',
>   strlen($payload)) . $payload;
>
> $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

when I echo $result. I shown "102".
What does this mean?

Comment: It means you should read the [documentation for the return value](http://php.net/fwrite) -- Congrats!  You wrote 102 bytes!  Don't forget to test `if $result === false`, too. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**1xx Informational**

```
 **102 Processing (WebDAV; RFC 2518)**
```

As a WebDAV request may contain many sub-requests involving file operations, it may take a long time to complete the request. This code indicates that the server has received and is processing the request, but no response is available yet.[2] This prevents the client from timing out and assuming the request was lost. Source of this  [**Wikipedia** List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)